# Spring OAuth: Custom form for authenticating authorization endpoint

Tags: spring, oauth, spring-security

How can I set up a custom login form to protect my /oauth/authorize endpoint in an Spring Boot Application that is both a Authorization and Resource Server? I want to achieve that a user has to log in to make requests to /oauth/authorize. All resources, that are not /login and /oauth/** should be handled as secured resources protected by OAuth (requiring a valid access token)

So when a user calls localhost:1234/oauth/authorize?client_id=client&response_type=token&redirect_uri=http://localhost:5678 he is first redirected to the login form and after successfully loggin in redirect to the /oauth/authorize endpoint where the implicit OAuth flow proceeds.

When I try the following it works, using the standard basic authentication popup window

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class OAuthConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(final ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients)
            throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory()
                .withClient("client")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("implicit", "refresh_token")
                .scopes("read");
    }

}
```

The Resource config

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceConfiguration
        extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter
{

    @Override
    public void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login").permitAll().and()
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
        // @formatter:on
    }
}
```

The Web Security config

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfiguration
        extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/oauth/authorize").authenticated().and()
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll().and().httpBasic();
    }

}
```

but as soon as I replace httpBasic() with the following it fails:

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfiguration
        extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
         http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/oauth/authorize").authenticated().and()
         .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll().and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").and().csrf()
         .disable();
    }

}
```

and my POST from the login Page is not redirected, it always just returns to /login

The output from the console is as following

```
o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/css/**'
o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/js/**'
o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/images/**'
o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/**/favicon.ico'
o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/error'
o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/oauth/token']
o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/oauth/token'
o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/oauth/token_key']
o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/oauth/token_key'
o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/oauth/check_token']
o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/oauth/check_token'
o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : No matches found
o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.ResourceServerConfiguration$NotOAuthRequestMatcher@5fe3eb5f
o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : matched
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 1 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 2 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 3 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@51c78264
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 4 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/logout'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 5 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter'
o.s.s.o.p.a.BearerTokenExtractor         : Token not found in headers. Trying request parameters.
o.s.s.o.p.a.BearerTokenExtractor         : Token not found in request parameters.  Not an OAuth2 request.
p.a.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter : No token in request, will continue chain.
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 6 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 7 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 8 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@90541710: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@166c8: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: BDCE2D7EA7252AEA2506633726B8BA19; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 9 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 10 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 11 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/login'
o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /login; Attributes: [#oauth2.throwOnError(permitAll)]
o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@90541710: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@166c8: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: BDCE2D7EA7252AEA2506633726B8BA19; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased       : Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@bba9bfc, returned: 1
o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Authorization successful
o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Chain processed normally
s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding an [@Order(-10)](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/annotation/Order.html) to the WebSecurityConfig resolves the issue. I think this annoation ensures that the WebSecurityConfig is used before the ResourceConfig. My final configuration looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@Order(-10)
public class WebSecurityConfig
        extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.parentAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);

    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/oauth/authorize").authenticated()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable();
        // @formatter:on
    }

}
```